# Parse XML in Python with lxml.etree

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

How can I parse this site (http://www.tvspielfilm.de/tv-programm/rss/heute2015.xml) with python to get for example the tv programm for today on SAT at 20:15?
I've tried the Python library lxml.etree, but I failed:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import lxml.etree as ET 
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.tvspielfilm.de/tv-programm/rss/heute2015.xml')
xml = response.read()

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

for item in root.findall('SAT'):
    title = item.find('title').text
    print title
```

Comment: If you use findall('SAT') This parser will search for all tags named SAT. Since there isn't such a tag, there would be no result. I recommend you to loop through all items 'item' tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `Element.findall` uses xpath expression as an argument. `'SAT'` finds only direct children that are named SAT of the root node, witch is `'rss'`. If you need to find a tag anyway in the document use `'.//SAT'`.

The expression `'.//items'` is what you looking for:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import lxml.etree as ET 
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen('some/url/to.xml')
xml = response.read()

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

for item in root.findall('.//item'):
    title = item.find('title').text
    print title
```

Comment: for item in root.findall('.*/item'):

        title = item.find('title').text

        print title

worked for me.

Comment: @Arpegius can u plz help on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63079625/python-xml-parse-and-getelementsbytagname