# Python XML Parse and getElementsByTagName

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I was trying to parse the following xml and fetch specific tags that i'm interested in around my business need. and i guess i'm doing something wrong. Not sure how to parse my required tags?? Wanted to leverage pandas, so that i can further filter for specifics. Apprentice all the support

**My XMl coming from URI**

```
<couponfeed>
 <TotalMatches>1459</TotalMatches>
 <TotalPages>3</TotalPages>
 <PageNumberRequested>1</PageNumberRequested>
 <link type="TEXT">
  <categories>
   <category id="1">Apparel</category>
  </categories>
  <promotiontypes>
    <promotiontype id="11">Percentage off</promotiontype>
   </promotiontypes>
   <offerdescription>25% Off Boys Quiksilver Apparel. Shop now at Macys.com! Valid 7/23 through 7/25!</offerdescription>
   <offerstartdate>2020-07-24</offerstartdate>
   <offerenddate>2020-07-26</offerenddate>
   <clickurl>https://click.synergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=Z&offerid=777210.100474694&type=3&subid=0</clickurl>
    <impressionpixel>https://ad.synergy.com/fs-bin/show?id=ZNAweM&bids=777210.100474694&type=3&subid=0</impressionpixel>
    <advertiserid>3184</advertiserid>
    <advertisername>cys.com</advertisername>
    <network id="1">US Network</network>
  </link>
 <link type="TEXT">
  <categories>
   <category id="1">Apparel</category>
  </categories>
  <promotiontypes>
   <promotiontype id="11">Percentage off</promotiontype>
  </promotiontypes>
  <offerdescription>25% Off Boys' Quiksilver Apparel. Shop now at Macys.com! Valid 7/23 through 7/25!</offerdescription>
  <offerstartdate>2020-07-24</offerstartdate>
  <offerenddate>2020-07-26</offerenddate>
  <clickurl>https://click.synergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=ZZvk49eM&offerid=777210.100474695&type=3&subid=0</clickurl>
  <impressionpixel>https://ad.synergy.com/fs-bin/show?id=ZZvk49NAwbids=777210.100474695&type=3&subid=0</impressionpixel>
  <advertiserid>3184</advertiserid>
  <advertisername>cys.com</advertisername>
  <network id="1">US Network</network>
 </link>
```

**My Code**

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import urllib
import pandas as pd 
url = "http://couponfeed.synergy.com/coupon?token=xxxxxxxxx122b&network=1&resultsperpage=500"
xmldoc = minidom.parse(urllib.request.urlopen(url)) 

#itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('clickurl')


df_cols = ["promotiontype","category","offerdescription", "offerstartdate", "offerenddate", "clickurl","impressionpixel","advertisername","network"]
rows = []

for entry in xmldoc.couponfeed:
    s_promotiontype = couponfeed.get("promotiontype","")
    s_category = couponfeed.get("category","")
    s_offerdescription = couponfeed.get("offerdescription", "")
    s_offerstartdate = couponfeed.get("offerstartdate", "")
    s_offerenddate = couponfeed.get("offerenddate", "")
    s_clickurl = couponfeed.get("clickurl", "")
    s_impressionpixel = couponfeed.get("impressionpixel", "")
    s_advertisername = couponfeed.get("advertisername","")
    s_network = couponfeed.get ("network","")
       
        
    rows.append({"promotiontype":s_promotiontype, "category": s_category, "offerdescription": s_offerdescription, 
                 "offerstartdate": s_offerstartdate, "offerenddate": s_offerenddate,"clickurl": s_clickurl,"impressionpixel":s_impressionpixel,
                 "advertisername": s_advertisername,"network": s_network})

out_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=df_cols)


out_df.to_csv(r"C:\\Users\rai\Downloads\\merchants_offers_share.csv", index=False)
```

Trying easy way but i dont get any results

```
import lxml.etree as ET 
import urllib

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://couponfeed.synergy.com/coupon?token=xxxxxd39f4e5fe392a25538bb122b&network=1&resultsperpage=500')
xml = response.read()

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

for item in root.findall('.//item'):
    title = item.find('category').text
    print (title)
```

another try

```
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd 
import urllib

    url = "http://couponfeed.synergy.com/coupon?token=xxxxxxd39f4e5fe392a25538bb122b&network=1&resultsperpage=500"
    xtree = etree.parse(urllib.request.urlopen(url)) 
    
    for value in xtree.xpath("/root/couponfeed/categories"):
        print(value.text)
```

Comment: What about your code isn't working?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica so i get AttributeError: 'Document' object has no attribute 'couponfeed'

Comment: Can you provide the working xml doc so I can test it?  As is, the xml has syntax errors

Comment: @ReinstateMonica is it possible to share privately please?

Comment: Sure, send me an email at: forspam103 (at) gmail.com

Comment: make sure to include your username in the title so I can find it

Comment: @ReinstateMonica sent. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req
# html = req.get('http://couponfeed.synergy.com/coupon?token=xxxxxxxxx122b&network=1&resultsperpage=500')
html = '''
<couponfeed>
 <TotalMatches>1459</TotalMatches>
 <TotalPages>3</TotalPages>
 <PageNumberRequested>1</PageNumberRequested>
 <link type="TEXT">
  <categories>
   <category id="1">Apparel</category>
  </categories>
  <promotiontypes>
    <promotiontype id="11">Percentage off</promotiontype>
   </promotiontypes>
   <offerdescription>25% Off Boys Quiksilver Apparel. Shop now at Macys.com! Valid 7/23 through 7/25!</offerdescription>
   <offerstartdate>2020-07-24</offerstartdate>
   <offerenddate>2020-07-26</offerenddate>
   <clickurl>https://click.synergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=Z&offerid=777210.100474694&type=3&subid=0</clickurl>
    <impressionpixel>https://ad.synergy.com/fs-bin/show?id=ZNAweM&bids=777210.100474694&type=3&subid=0</impressionpixel>
    <advertiserid>3184</advertiserid>
    <advertisername>cys.com</advertisername>
    <network id="1">US Network</network>
  </link>
 </couponfeed>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
df_cols = [
    "promotiontype", "category", "offerdescription", "offerstartdate",
    "offerenddate", "clickurl", "impressionpixel", "advertisername", "network"
]
rows = [df_cols]

links = doc.couponfeed.links  # Get all links
for link in links:
    row = []
    for col in df_cols:
        row.append(link.select(col).text)  # Get col text
    rows.append(row)

utils.save2csv('merchants_offers_share.csv', rows)  # Save to csv file
```

Result:

```
promotiontype,category,offerdescription,offerstartdate,offerenddate,clickurl,impressionpixel,advertisername,network
Percentage off,Apparel,25% Off Boys Quiksilver Apparel. Shop now at Macys.com! Valid 7/23 through 7/25!,2020-07-24,2020-07-26,https://click.synergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=Z&offerid=777210.100474694&type=3&subid=0,https://ad.synergy.com/fs-bin/show?id=ZNAweM&bids=777210.100474694&type=3&subid=0,cys.com,US Network
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Remove the last empty row

```
import io
with io.open('merchants_offers_share.csv', "rb+") as f:
    f.seek(-1,2)
    l = f.read()
    if l == b"\n":
        f.seek(-2,2)
        f.truncate()
```

Comment: THANK YOU. Works like a charm. quick question why does csv output leaves one empty row (i.e) i get records with an alternative empty records. How do i get a nice .csv without empty rows?

Comment: @sunnybabau I'm glad to be able to help you. The last empty row is for the convenience of appending data. If you don't need it, you can delete it in the above way. I changed the answer.

Comment: can u plz suggest a feasible solution for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63122779/python-parsing-html-from-url-into-pd-valueerror-no-tables-found?noredirect=1#comment111624853_63122779

Answer (score 0):

First, the xml document wasn't parsing because you copied a raw ampersand `&` from the source page, which is like a keyword in xml.  When your browser renders xml (or html), it converts `&amp;` into `&`.

As for the code, the easiest way to get the data is to iterate over `df_cols`, then execute `getElementsByTagName` for each column, which will return a list of elements for the given column.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import pandas as pd
import urllib

limit = 500
url = f"http://couponfeed.synergy.com/coupon?token=xxxxxxxxx122b&network=1&resultsperpage={limit}"


xmldoc = minidom.parse(urllib.request.urlopen(url))

df_cols = ["promotiontype","category","offerdescription", "offerstartdate", "offerenddate", "clickurl","impressionpixel","advertisername","network"]

# create an object for each row
rows = [{} for i in range(limit)]

nodes = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("promotiontype")
node = nodes[0]

for row_name in df_cols:

    # get results for each row_name
    nodes = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName(row_name)
    for i, node in enumerate(nodes):
        rows[i][row_name] = node.firstChild.nodeValue


out_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=df_cols)

nodes = et.getElementsByTagName("promotiontype")
node = nodes[0]

for row_name in df_cols:
    nodes = et.getElementsByTagName(row_name)
    for i, node in enumerate(nodes):
        rows[i][row_name] = node.firstChild.nodeValue


out_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=df_cols)
```

This isn't the most efficient way to do this, but I'm not sure how else to using `minidom`.  If efficiency is a concern, I'd recommend using [`lxml`](https://pypi.org/project/lxml/) instead.

Comment: Tried LXML above, not sure what i'm i missing here--updated my post with my try

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no issue with parsing your XML from URL (since link is not available on our end), your first `lxml` can work if you parse on actual nodes. Specifically, there is no `<item>` node in XML document.

Instead use `link`. And consider a nested list/dict comprehension to migrate content to a data frame. For `lxml` you can swap out `findall` and `xpath` to return same result.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{item.tag: item.text if item.text.strip() != "" else item.find("*").text
                       for item in lnk.findall("*") if item is not None} 
                       for lnk in root.findall('.//link')])
                       
print(df)
#   categories  promotiontypes                                   offerdescription  ... advertiserid advertisername     network
# 0    Apparel  Percentage off  25% Off Boys Quiksilver Apparel. Shop now at M...  ...         3184        cys.com  US Network
# 1    Apparel  Percentage off  25% Off Boys' Quiksilver Apparel. Shop now at ...  ...         3184        cys.com  US Network
```

Comment: thanks .. So I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: You might have `<link>` nodes without child elements. See edit filtering out `None` `item` in inner `for`

Comment: sorry i get <Response [403]>. But at the same time the below solution provided by @dabingsou works, which implies nothing wrong with the URL. However Thank you for your support

Comment: I like your approach, not sure what is the issue here can u please help with this one parsing this into a datafram http://www.ebay.com/rps/feed/v1.1/epnexcluded/EBAY-US?limit=200

Comment: Did you try at all? Simply replace `.//link` with `.//item` for ebay XML. As for other issue, don't know why you receive the error but has nothing to do with this code. This answer above works on your posted XML. Check API instructions of accessing URL. Maybe you have to send params/headers?

Comment: Thank you. Yes i get <Response [403]>  my code                                              
import lxml.etree as ET 
import urllib

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.ebay.com/rps/feed/v1.1/epnexcluded/EBAY-US')
xml = response.read()

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for item in root.findall('.//item'):
    
    
    df = pd.DataFrame([{item.tag: item.text if item.text.strip() != "" else item.find("*").text
                       for item in lnk.findall("*") if item is not None} 
                       for lnk in root.findall('.//item')])
                       
print(df)

Comment: Try putting the whole URL path including `https://...`.

Comment: Yes sir I did no luck. I have posted my ebay question here and tagged you as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124680/feedparser-to-dataframe-doesnt-ouput-all-columns and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63122779/python-parsing-html-from-url-into-pd-valueerror-no-tables-found?noredirect=1#comment111624853_63122779

Comment: But an empty data frame means you do read the XML but are not parsing it correctly. This is different than URL error.