# Feedparser to dataframe doesnt ouput all columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I parsing a URL from feedparser and trying to get all columns, but i do not get all columns as a out put, not sure where the issue is. If you execute the below. I do not get data for few columns, but the data do exist as u can check in browser.

my code

```
import feedparser
import pandas as pd 

xmldoc = feedparser.parse('http://www.ebay.com/rps/feed/v1.1/epnexcluded/EBAY-US')
df_cols = [
    "title", "url", "endsAt", "image225","currency"
    "price", "orginalPrice", "discountPercentage", "quantity", "shippingCost","dealUrl"
]
rows = []

for entry in xmldoc.entries:
    s_title = entry.get("title","")
    s_url = entry.get("url", "")
    s_endsAt = entry.get("endsAt", "")
    s_image225 = entry.get("image225", "")
    s_currency = entry.get("currency", "")
    s_price = entry.get("price","")
    s_orginalPrice = entry.get("orginalPrice","")
    s_discountPercentage = entry.get ("discountPercentage","")
    s_quantity = entry.get("quantity","")
    s_shippingCost = entry.get("shippingCost", "")
    s_dealUrl = entry.get("dealUrl", "")#.replace('YOURUSERIDHERE','2427312')
       
        
    rows.append({"title":s_title, "url": s_url, "endsAt": s_endsAt, 
                 "image225": s_image225,"currency": s_currency,"price":s_price,
                 "orginalPrice": s_orginalPrice,"discountPercentage": s_discountPercentage,"quantity": s_quantity,
                 "shippingCost": s_shippingCost,"dealUrl": s_dealUrl})

out_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=df_cols)

out_df
```

tried this, but this doesn't give me any data only few columns (headers i suppose)

```
import lxml.etree as ET 
import urllib

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.ebay.com/rps/feed/v1.1/epnexcluded/EBAY-US')
xml = response.read()

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for item in root.findall('.*/item'):
       
    df = pd.DataFrame([{item.tag: item.text if item.text.strip() != "" else item.find("*").text
                       for item in lnk.findall("*") if item is not None} 
                       for lnk in root.findall('.//item')])
                       
df
```

Is is possible to iterate the URL offset within an array as below and result the output to a PD. When I try this it does work partially with issues (i.e) I have few elements missing, resulting in this error `AttributeError: object has no attribute 'price', shipping cost etc.,` How do we handle  if null for an element?

**my code**

```
 import feedparser
    import pandas as pd
    #from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req
    getdeals = ['http://www.ebay.com/rps/feed/v1.1/epnexcluded/EBAY-US?limit=200',
            'http://www.ebay.com/rps/feed/v1.1/epnexcluded/EBAY-US?limit=200&offset=200',
            'http://www.ebay.com/rps/feed/v1.1/epnexcluded/EBAY-US?limit=200&offset=400']
    
    posts=[]
    for urls in getdeals:
        feed = feedparser.parse(urls)
        for deals in feed.entries:
            print (deals)
            posts.append((deals.title,deals.endsat,deals.image225,deals.price,deals.originalprice,deals.discountpercentage,deals.shippingcost,deals.dealurl))
    df=pd.DataFrame(posts,columns=['title','endsat','image2255','price','originalprice','discountpercentage','shippingcost','dealurl'])
    df.tail()
```

Also , similarly how to loop multiple JSON responses

```
 url= ["https://merchants.apis.com/v4/publisher/159663/offers?country=US&limit=2000",
"https://merchants.apis.com/v4/publisher/159663/offers?country=US&offset=2001&limit=2000"]
    
    
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    response = response.json()
    
    
    name = []
    logo = []
    date_added = []
    description = []
    for i in range(len(response['offers'])):
        name.append(response['offers'][i]['merchant_details']['name'])
        logo.append(response['offers'][i]['merchant_details']['metadata']['logo'])
        date_added.append(response['offers'][i]['date_added'])
        description.append(response['offers'][i]['description'])
         try:
            verticals.append(response['offers'][i]['merchant_details']['verticals'][0])
        except IndexError:
            verticals.append('NA')
        pass
        
    data1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':name,'logo':logo,'verticals':verticals, 'date_added':date_added,'description':description})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method.

```
import pandas as pd
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req

getdeals = ['http://www.ebay.com/rps/feed/v1.1/epnexcluded/EBAY-US?limit=200',
            'http://www.ebay.com/rps/feed/v1.1/epnexcluded/EBAY-US?limit=200&offset=200',
            'http://www.ebay.com/rps/feed/v1.1/epnexcluded/EBAY-US?limit=200&offset=400']
    
posts=[]
header = ['title','endsAt','image255','price','originalPrice','discountPercentage','shippingCost','dealUrl']
for url in getdeals:
    try: # It's a good habit to have try and exception in your code.
        feed = SimplifiedDoc(req.get(url))
        for deals in feed.selects('item'):
            row = []
            for h in header: row.append(deals.select(h+">text()")) # Returns None when the element does not exist
            posts.append(row)
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        
df=pd.DataFrame(posts,columns=header)
df.tail()
```

Comment: THANK YOU. Everything works.. just one issue the image2255 column is always coming as NULL, though the data exists for it in fact it always have values??

Also, how about using the same array style for JSON response. I have updated the example.

Comment: the merchants.apis.com url for JSON response one in my updated above example, i have to fake it, as i'm not comfortable sharing in public, but can share your privately if you can kindly share your e-mail..Thx

Comment: @sunnybabau First, change image2255 to image255. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @sunnybabau Second, it is possible to use the same array style for JSON responses. You can also post a JSON response data as an example.

Comment: Ohh sorry I messed up my schema. Regarding JSON response. Yes I did update my post above as an example. When I try with array I get error. I can send you privately working URL if needed. Thx

Comment: I have sent my working code for your kind review. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Because the Ebay XML has a default namespace in root you need to define a prefix to this namespace URI in order to parse by named nodes. See how namespace dictionary is used in second argument of `findall` and the `.tag` needs namespace removed from retrieved value. Do note the opening `for` loop is ***not*** required for below list/dict comprehension solution.

```
import lxml.etree as ET 
import urllib
import pandas as pd

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.ebay.com/rps/feed/v1.1/epnexcluded/EBAY-US')
xml = response.read()

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
nmsp = {'doc': 'http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/rps/v1/feed'}
   
df = pd.DataFrame([{item.tag.replace(f"{{{nmsp['doc']}}}", ''): item.text 
                           if item.text.strip() != "" else item.find("*").text
                   for item in lnk.findall("*") if item is not None} 
                   for lnk in root.findall('.//doc:item', nmsp)])
```

**Output** *(running exact posted code above)*

```
df
#         itemId                                              title  ... shippingCost                                dealUrl
#0  372639986116  Samsung Galaxy BUDS SM-R170 (Bluetooth 5.0) He...  ...         0.00  https://www.ebay.com/deals/6052526231
#1  153918933129  Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen7, 14" FHD IPS, i...  ...         0.00  https://www.ebay.com/deals/6052642213
#2  283899231838  Ray Ban RB4278 628271 51 Black Matte Black Pla...  ...         0.00  https://www.ebay.com/deals/6051914268
#3  283957227324                  Ghost of Tsushima - PlayStation 4  ...         0.00  https://www.ebay.com/deals/6052642134
#4  202905303442  Samsung Galaxy S20+ Plus SM-G985F/DS 128GB 8GB...  ...         0.00  https://www.ebay.com/deals/6052752611
#5  332946625819  DEWALT DCB6092 20V/60V MAX FLEXVOLT 9 Ah Li-Io...  ...         0.00  https://www.ebay.com/deals/6052523001
#6  264175647395  Citizen Eco-Drive Men's Silver Dial Black Leat...  ...         0.00  https://www.ebay.com/deals/6051783829
#7  303374676252  Champion Authentic Cotton 9-Inch Men's Shorts ...  ...         0.00  https://www.ebay.com/deals/6051880500
#8  202940881433   Samsung QN65Q90TAFXZA 65" 4K QLED Smart UHD T...  ...         0.00  https://www.ebay.com/deals/6052527037
#9  400789484589  Light Blue by Dolce & Gabbana D&G Perfume Wome...  ...         0.00  https://www.ebay.com/deals/6052122816
```

Comment: Sir your code is also working for amzn. Just that i get whole HTML tag in description, is there a way to break that description into multiple columns please

Comment: my amzn codeimport lxml.etree as ET 
import urllib
import pandas as pd
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://rssfeeds.s3.amazonaws.com/goldbox')
xml = response.read()
root = ET.fromstring(xml)            
df = pd.DataFrame([{item.tag: item.text if item.text.strip() != "" else item.find("*").text
        for item in lnk.findall("*") if item is not None} 
        for lnk in root.findall('.//item')])

Comment: You may have to run a follow-up loop on the *description* column after this initial XML parse. Look into lxml's [html parser](https://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsing-html) or [`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) (which defaults to `lxml` as the engine).

Comment: sir is there a easy way to Iterate the Urls? I have updated my question with my try above